Align lists of list in html
I'm designing the bottom section for a website that should contain three lists, arranged horizontally, each with its own points, which are links or text.
I tried to create an unordered list, with 3 other unordered lists as points, each having its own <li> points.Then the outer list use flexbox to display other lists titles and it work, but link1,link2,etc are still horizontal.


.endpage {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.endpage ul {
  display: flex;
}

.endpage-titles {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  font-family: djr-banner-bold;
  font-size: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-shadow: 1px #000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
<div class="endpage">
  <ul class="endpage-titles">
    <ul class="endpage-subtitles">CONTACTS</ul>
    <li>link1</li>
    <li>link2</li>
    <li>link3</li>
    <ul class="endpage-subtitles">LINKS</ul>
    <li>link1</li>
    <li>link2</li>
    <ul class="endpage-subtitles">MAPS</ul>
    <li>link1</li>
  </ul>
</div>




Your HTML is invalid. Only a <li> can be a child of a <ul> (not another <ul>). Also, a <li> and <ul> cannot be siblings

The best way to mark up navigation menus in 2024 is to simply use <nav> and <a>. The <nav> element automatically conveys the correct semantics for accessibility.
These days, the only time you should use the <ul> element is to mark up a regular bulleted list in the main part of your page.
In a similar vein, the most semantically correct way to mark up a footer is to use <footer>.


body {
  margin: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

footer {
  margin: 0 -1em -1em;          /* stretch footer to the viewport edge */
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;                /* display footer items beside each other */
  gap: 2em;                     /* with this gap in-between */
}

footer, footer a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: gold;
}

footer h4 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
}

footer>div, footer nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

footer>div {
  gap: 1em;
}

footer nav {
  gap: 2px;
}
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan.</p>

<footer>
  <div>
    <h4>Contacts</h4>
    <nav>
      <a href="">link 1</a>
      <a href="">link 2</a>
      <a href="">link 3</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>Links</h4>
    <nav>
      <a href="">link 4</a>
      <a href="">link 5</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>Maps</h4>
    <nav>
      <a href="">link 6</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</footer>



